# How to convert yuv420sp data to jpeg data？

Tags: android

Preview Data in camera is yuv420sp style data. But the data delivered in datacallback is jpeg data. How to convert yuv420sp data to jpeg data before datacallback?

It is very difficult to convert in JAVA layer. So what else method you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to convert. The Camera.PictureCallBack returns a JPEG. 
See "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)"